# CKEditor - How do I get the data from a ckeditor element that was not assigned an ID initially

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I just started using CKEditor, and I went through the API Documentation, which was really good, though there was some stuff left out.  At some point their help or documentation takes you to a page and says to post questions and look for answers on it on StackOverflow, so here I am.

In the documentation, it does say how to get the data or to look for changes based on an elements ID.
I have a page that the elements being created on it are dynamically generated and are not getting an ID as they are being dynamically generated.
These elements are `textarea` and `<div contenteditibable='true'`.
I know when CKEditor does its thing, it will create an ID on certain parts of the elements as well.
I know in HTML everything gets an ID in the DOM.
And I know that I am oversimplifying things.

Using CKEditor, how do I get the data or change event from something I don't know the ID for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the source code for [inlineall](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/17-08-04-06-04/full/samples/old/inlineall.html) sample. There is a pretty smart [event](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-instanceCreated) used which allows you getting to each editor instance (when it is created) and its element. Inside that event listener you can change initial editor configuration (with the help of other event to be more precise).

Editor has also [instanceReady](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-instanceReady) event which you can use in the same way to assign [change event](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change) that will capture all changes for particular editor instance. Finally inside the change event listener (as well as other [editor events](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor)), you can get access to editor for which the event was fired e.g.

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {
     evt.editor.on( 'change', function( e ) {
        console.log( e.editor );
        console.log( e.editor.element );
     } );
} );
```

Hope this helps you get started.

Comment: Thank you, the `'instanceReady'` helped a great deal.  
I ended up using the `instances` and `checkDirty()` property and method and looping through those to see what is changed and what information there is for each element / object.
I was using something similar to below...

`for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    if (CKEDITOR.instances[i].checkDirty()) {
        //do some stuff here.... 
        //the checkDirty() checks if the content is different than what is originally loaded
        // the i variable will actually return the element ID at this point
    });
}
`

Comment: Whatever works the best for you man but please note that inside change event listener you don’t need to loop through instances as you get exactly the editor which got changed. On the other hand there are some issues concerning change event so it might not get fired in every case you need it:
https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/14675, https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/14329

Comment: Thank you for that note on that. 

After the last post I did notice that, and realized that I didn't need it in the `on.change' event either.  So I did take it out of that, and made a separate button for a save feature.  Supposedly with CKEditor if you put it in a `<form>` tag / block the save button will automatically show up, but I already have that and I can't get it to work.  So I just have my own save button and then it does the loop through and checks what changed.